# How to find whether a checkbox is selected inside a div using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am having a div like

```
<div style="" id="listColumns">
   <input type="checkbox" id="77"/>Name
   <input type="checkbox" id="78"/>Designation
   <input type="checkbox" id="79"/>Address
   <input type="checkbox" id="80"/>Email - Id
   <input type="checkbox" id="81"/>Date Of Birth
</div>
```

I am trying to find what are all fields are checked using JQuery. How to do so?

Comment: Purely-numeric IDs are not valid HTML. Call them eg. `id="c77"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#listColumns :checked").each(function() {

    alert(this.id + " is checked");

});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("input:checked")
```

Go to [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) to read more about jQuery's powerful selectors.

Comment: you can then do .length on this to check if anything was found.

Answer (score 0):

You may get better performance by splitting out the selectors.

```
$("#listColumns").find("input:checked").each(function() {
       alert(this.id);
});
```